# Java. how to know that the function was executed?

Tags: java, android, callback, load

I have loadGraphics() function in my app. It takes a lot of time to be executed. I want to make loading screen, while this function is running. Can I create inside callback, which would have notified me about the function succeeds? Thanks in advance.

Comment: swing, awt, swt, android, ...?

Comment: @kiheru This app is for Android devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Just create a private boolean that can only be accessed in the class, setting it to false initially. Before beginning that loadGraphics(), just start a basic thread that has a callback in it if that boolean is true.

Then just add a statement at the end of loadGraphics() that sets the boolean to true.